Complex cross-correlation: conjugate first or second argument?
If I understand correctly the definition of cross-correlation, the complex conjugate is not applied to the same argument depending on whether we're working with deterministic signals or with stochastic processes.
For deterministic signals, here's the the Wikipedia page, citing Rabiner and Schafer:
$${\displaystyle (f\star g)[n]\ \triangleq \sum _{m=-\infty }^{\infty }{\overline {f[m]}}g[m+n]}$$
For random vectors, here's another section of the same Wikipedia page, citing Gubner 2006:
$${\displaystyle \operatorname {R} _{\mathbf {Z} \mathbf {W} }\triangleq \ \operatorname {E} [\mathbf {Z} \mathbf {W} ^{\rm {H}}]}$$
These two definitions are inconsistent with each other. I feel like I would prefer the latter because it is consistent with sesquilinear forms, which are linear in their first argument and semilinear in their second argument.
Here are some DSP.SE answers in which the "conjugate first argument" convention is being used:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/55087/74603
Correlation : Cross correlation why we need to multiply the samples
Auto-correlation of the sum of two generic signals
Efficient way to calculate $n$ first elements of cross-correlation using FFT (in Fourier domain)

Why has the DSP community adopted another convention than the statistical and mathematical communities? Is it because we prefer to apply both conjugation and time reversal to the same argument before convolving via FFT?
[EDIT: my question is different from this question which asked about the sign of temporal lag when cross-correlating real signals. The OP suggested to replace $(f\star g)[n]$ by $(f\star g)[-n]$. I am not suggesting that at all. What i am suggesting is to replace $(f\star g)[n]$ by its complex conjugate.]

just a remark: DSP very often concerns itself with working with random signals (after all, for signals that aren't random, the signal and the result holds no entropy, hence no information. The transport, extraction and communication of information is one of the main reasons we do DSP, be it for audio purposes, to communicate data in an optical fiber or to estimate the water content in air, for example). So, there's no separate "DSP community" that doesn't deal with random signals. For example, Rabiner (from Rabiner & Schafer) is famous (among other things) for pioneering hidden markov …

models: It doesn't get much more statistical. Schafer in turn is famous for speech coding, the art of understanding speech as a random source, and using stochastic method and statistics to minimize the bit rate that a compressed representation; you'll find Bayes, stochastic processes, and estimation theory all over their life work!

This question is similar to: Cross-correlation seems defined backwards. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MarcusMüller thank you. Indeed the historical importance of statistics (and sesquilinear algebra) in DSP is what prompted me to ask the question.

@DanBoschen thank you. I have edited the question to clarify the difference.

@iostanlen I want to make sure you saw my answer to that post as I detail there I my answer the use of the complex conjugate and its significance, this is what I thought might address your question.

Since there seems to be quite a bit of discussion and previous answers, I'll add a different perspective of that from the PSD.
The PSD has two definitions:
\begin{align}
\phi(\omega) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r(n)e^{-j\omega n} \\ &= \lim_{N\to\infty}E\left\{\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y(n)e^{-j\omega n}\right\rvert^{2}\right\}
\end{align}
which are equivalent. These can be shown equivalent by [1]
\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty}E\left\{\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}y(n)e^{-j\omega n}\right\rvert^{2}\right\} &= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}E\left[y(t)y^{*}(s)\right]e^{-j\omega(t-s)}
\end{align}
If we define the ACS as
\begin{equation}
r_{yy} = E\left[y(t)y^{*}(t-s)\right] = E\left[y^{*}(t)y(t+s)\right]
\end{equation}
then by allowing $\tau = t-s$, after some mild assumptions [1] (not related to the topic at hand) we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}r(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}
\end{equation}
On the contrary, if we define the ACS as
\begin{equation}
r_{yy} = E\left[y^{*}(t)y(t-s)\right] = E\left[y(t)y^{*}(t+s)\right]
\end{equation}
we instead get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}E\left[y^{*}(t)y(s)\right]e^{j\omega(t-s)} = \sum_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty}r(\tau)e^{j\omega\tau}
\end{equation}
This corresponds to the PSD at frequency $-\omega$ as opposed to the frequency $\omega$. For real signals, the difference in definition is not a problem, however, it is important for complex signals where the spectrum might not be mirrored. Thus, the first definition of $r_{yy}$ is typically desirable. The proof was adapted from [1], and you can see chapter 1 for more details.
[1] - Stoica, P., & Moses, R. L. (2005). Spectral analysis of signals (Vol. 452, pp. 25-26). Upper Saddle River, NJ: Pearson Prentice Hall.
